# GraphQL: Remove field from query string

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a graphQL server consumed by many clients and have a process that generates operations from introspection; problem is that the schema has a handful of nested queries that take arguments that I may or may not want to invoke.

given this generated operation

```
query Query($input: String!) {
  things(input: $input) {
     item1
     item2
     nestedQuery(nestedInput: $nestedInput) {
        nestedItem1
     }
  }   
}
```

is there a tool (other than string parsing, that's a given) to strip unwanted fields from here so that the query is transformed into

```
query Query($input: String!) {
  things(input: $input) {
     item1
     item2
  }   
}
```

Looking at the introspection JSON I can identify this item by the presence of `args` on the field `things` that is past the first depth - but I don't want to necessarily lose information on generation - I'd like those nested queries to be visible/documented.

Comment: You can use `@skip` directive to skip the fields with args.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand how you are generating the GraphQL document here, but assuming that you have total control over it, you can use the default directives (`@skip` and `@include`) to skip or include fields based on a condition.

For example, the following document will skip the `nestedQuery` field when executing. You may use a variable value as the value for the argument `if`.

```
query Query($input: String!) {
  things(input: $input) {
     item1
     item2
     nestedQuery(nestedInput: $nestedInput) @skip(if: true) {
        nestedItem1
     }
  }   
}
```

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/amplify-graphql-docs-generator after an introspection query

Comment: interesting! I will take a look in that directive, thank you.